# PowerMockito Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I am testing a `static method` using `PowerMockito` but unfortunately getting `ClassCastException`. Notexactly sure if I am not following the syntax rules.

Code to be tested:

```
List<IClientUserPrefDto> proxyPrefs = (List<IClientUserPrefDto>) DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(config.geteSignatureSecurityUser().getUserPreferences(), entity, attribute);
```

Junit/PowerMockcode

```
PowerMockito.when( ( List<IClientUserPrefDto>) DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute( anyListOf( IClientUserPrefDto.class ), any( String.class ), any( String.class ) ) ).thenReturn( list );
```

stack trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute()
getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute() should return IClientUserPrefDto
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

at    test.com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.tag.TestUIConfigPreferenceTag.testDoStartTag(TestUIConfigPreferenceTag.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: It looks like `getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute` returns only one instance of `IClientUserPrefDto` and not an `ArrayList` of it.

Comment: I know that, but is there any work around that? This is actually the issue that it returns instance of IClientUserPrefDto. The method under test also casts this to List<IClientUserPrefDto>

Comment: Theres a couple different ways around casting to a `List`. You could initialize the `List` first, then call `proxyPrefs.add((IClientUserPrefDto) DtoUtils.getCl...)` or you can not have `proxyPrefs` as a `List`.

Comment: List has been initialized and I've added instance of IClientUserPref to it. I cannot change the code to satisfy my test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in `DtoUtils` called `getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttributeAsList`.

```
static List<IClientUserPrefDto> getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttributeAsList(...) {
     return (List<IClientUserPrefDto>) DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(...
...
}
```

Then, you can mock it like:

```
PowerMockito.when(DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttributeAsList(anyListOf(IClientUserPrefDto.class),any(String.class),any(String.class))).thenReturn(list);
```

This is a workaround to the problem. But in this case, the method `when` definitely needs to receive a method that returns a list.

Comment: Im pretty sure that wont work. The issue as I see it here is the casting to List, you are essentially just moving it to a separate function and not fixing the problem.

Comment: I think the exception happens in `thenReturn` method from PowerMockito. There is no casting exception in this code `List<IClientUserPrefDto> proxyPrefs = (List<IClientUserPrefDto>) DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(...);`

Comment: Hmm. Interesting.

Comment: I agree with Michael. This is not the solution at all. I wish we could change stuff like alayor did here. I would never post this question if I could change or create a new method.

Comment: @Michael. PowerMock throws WrongReturntype exception which is == ClassCastException if you think about it.